# Special case of $\varepsilon-\delta$ continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Realted with the of "epsilon-delta" definition of continuity, I am looking some example of a continuous function defined on [0,1] such that $|f(t)-f(s)|<\delta/2$ whenever $|t-s|\leq \delta$.

Of coruse, any continuosly differentiable $f$ with $|f'(t)|<1/2$ for each $t\in [0,1]$ satisfies the above condition, but do you know others examples?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: This condition is known as [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), with constant $\frac12$.

Comment: Yes, but there is a not Lipschitz function such the above condition is satifies?

Comment: There are many Lipschitz functions that aren't differentiable. Take, for instance, $|x|$ (or in your case $\frac12|x|$), or a triangular wave. I know there exists functions that are differentiable at significantly fewer points, but I don't know of a concrete example.

Comment: The Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable, or the Hilbert space-filling curve.  The question (sorry for not writing the statement correctly) is if there are not Lipschitz functions.

Comment: Then have a look at the [following theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) that I just found. Turns out I was wrong, and Lipschitz continuous functions are necessarily almost everywhere differentiable.

Comment: Yes, the Rademacher theorem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Define the periodic sawtooth function
$$\phi(t):=\left\{\eqalign{|t|\quad &\qquad(-1\leq t\leq 1),\cr \phi(t+2)&\qquad\forall\>t\in{\mathbb R}\ .\cr}\right.$$

Then choose an $N\gg1$ and put
$$f(t):={1\over2}\sum_{n=1}^N{1\over 2^n}\>\phi\bigl(2^n t\bigr)\ .$$

Comment: Many thanks Christian Blatter!!  What a beatiful  "strange" function! ;)